# What is in android.util.Log#println_native()?

Tags: java, android, logging, android-source, println

[Here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/util/Log.java) is the `android.util.Log` source code.

At the very bottom (line 340), what is in the method:

```
public static native int println_native(int bufID,
        int priority, String tag, String msg);
```

---

i guess `println_native()` is more or less like its `println()`, just with an `int bufID` different.

But even i got the codes of `println_native()`, i still lack `com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit` (line 19, the `import`) to simulate `android.util.Log` in old Android version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just did some digging in the android source code. This function maps to

```
static jint android_util_Log_println_native(JNIEnv* env, jobject clazz,
    jint bufID, jint priority, jstring tagObj, jstring msgObj)
{
const char* tag = NULL;
const char* msg = NULL;

if (msgObj == NULL) {
    jniThrowNullPointerException(env, "println needs a message");
    return -1;
}

if (bufID < 0 || bufID >= LOG_ID_MAX) {
    jniThrowNullPointerException(env, "bad bufID");
    return -1;
}

if (tagObj != NULL)
    tag = env->GetStringUTFChars(tagObj, NULL);
msg = env->GetStringUTFChars(msgObj, NULL);

int res = __android_log_buf_write(bufID, (android_LogPriority)priority, tag, msg);

if (tag != NULL)
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(tagObj, tag);
env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(msgObj, msg);

return res;
}
```

Basically this then passes the arguments to the driver in the system which goes and writes to the Log buffer. Log buffer is pointed by `/dev/log` in the Linux kernel.

Comment: Do you mean you downloaded the source and the above codes show up?

Comment: Thanks. Could you quote where exact you traced to those codes? And let me know where to download it?

Comment: Try this one http://code.google.com/p/pdroid/source/browse/trunk/frameworks/base/core/jni/android_util_Log.cpp?r=57

Comment: one up. Could you explain how to trace it? I traced it down to line 340 of the Log.java class and don't know where to look next.

Comment: I am hoping that line 340 is a call to 'public static native int println_native(int bufID, int priority, String tag, String msg);'. This will correspond to the function posted from Log.cpp. The above function then makes a call to the Log buffer in Linux to post the message. DDMS reads this buffer to show the logs.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have downloaded the sdk, you can use `find` to dig files.
Java code is linked to cpp code through jni.

In your case, you can use this command to find the related files:

```
find framework -type f -name "*.cpp" -exec grep "println_native" {} \; -ls
```

then you'll see that your java function is linked to this file : framework/base/core/jni/android_util_Log.cpp