# What is the semantics of the return value of the Android logging functions (e.g. Log.v() )?

Tags: android, logging

The Android logging functions return an `int`. The documentation [does not say](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) anything about them. What does the return value mean?

When I try in my simple app, I get `18` for the following `Log.v` call:

```
android.util.Log.v("MyApp", "my message");
```

Comment: Next question: Why on earth isn't this documented?! The Android API seems to have been documented by amateurs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the number of bytes written, from the underlying `println`.

Comment: I see that the byte count is: tag + message + extra 3 bytes. Any idea that these are?

Comment: @GabrielPetrovay Could be the EOL, don't know what the rest is.

Comment: Another extra value would be the log level. Here's the underlying native implementation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16548172/what-is-in-android-util-logprintln-native